# How integrate QR code to Jasper Report Studio

Tags: jasper-reports, barcode, classcastexception

I'm using jasper report studio. I use a barcode type 128, in the preview of the jasper report if it shows me, when processing the report from java (eclipse) it shows me the following error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/krysalis/barcode4j/HumanReadablePlacement
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2128)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getPrivateMethod(ObjectStreamClass.java:1475)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1700(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:498)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:472)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:472)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:369)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:598)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1843)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1843)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1713)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2000)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:791)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2169)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2245)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:552)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseReport.readObject(JRBaseReport.java:770)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2136)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2027)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1535)
java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:422)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:140)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:116)
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(JRLoader.java:107)
icrperusa.utils.Reports.getReportcn(Reports.java:37)
icrperusa.servlet.reports.FacturaElectronica.doGet(FacturaElectronica.java:54)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

In java it imports the barcode4j-2.1.jar library.

Answer (score 1):

easy, you need to import the dependencie.
Double check because this class is IN the barcode4j.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: David, It is added in pom.xml?

Comment: Yes, it should be added in pom.xml

Comment: show this error.   Error reading file /home/juan/.m2/repository/net/sf/barcode4j/barcode4j/2.1/barcode4j-2.1.jar
/home/juan/.m2/repository/net/sf/barcode4j/barcode4j/2.1/barcode4j-2.1.jar (No such file or directory)

Comment: you should download again this resources. Try removing the barcode4j folder of your .m2 folder or update Maven Configuration in Eclipse (mark the checkbox of force)

Comment: not work, show the same error